# Access VBA ListBox ItemData Variant is always 1

Tags: vba, listbox

I have a form with multiple list boxes and all work fine save 1!  This is the only list box whose source is number data-type.  I know this shouldn't matter, but what I'm seeing is that for this list box *only* the variant returned is always 1, and I cannot understand why the others (data-type text) work properly and this one doesn't.  All of my Google searches and MSN searches and here on StackOverflow have not helped my specific issue though there's a LOT out there about ListBoxes.  Please help!

Edit: Sorry @Mat's Mug...I was hoping that wouldn't be necessary as it's lengthy with all the checking going on, but here's the gist.

```
For Each ctl In Form.Controls
       With ctl
            Select Case .ControlType

               Case acListBox

               If .Visible = True Then
                   .SetFocus
                   ItemCount = .ItemsSelected.Count

                   If .ItemsSelected.Count > 0 Then

                       For Each varItm In .ItemsSelected

                          If .Name = "lstRating" Then
                              sWhereClause = sWhereClause & "ThisRating=" & .ItemData(varItem) & " Or ThatRating = " & .ItemData(varItem)
                          Else
                              sWhereClause = sWhereClause & Mid(.Name, 4, Len(.Name)) & " = """ & .ItemData(varItm) & """"
                          End If

                       Next varItm
                   End If

               End If

           End Select
     End With
Next ctl
```

Note: When .Name = "lstRating" is True is the line where varItem returned is 1 regardless of what is selected.  The list box is populated with values from 1 to 5 in 0.5 increments.

Comment: Showing us some code might help us help you here...

Comment: What application are you working in?

Comment: I'm using MS Access.  Sorry for the poor code entry...the forum wouldn't allow me to do it properly...I tried!

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @Ken White!  *grin*

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can't believe I was overlooking it for hours...I was using varItem in the offending line when it's defined at varItm, no "e"!  TOTALLY an oversight on my part.  Thanks all for looking into this!